# is there any way to dynamically add formclass to the view using url in django?

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I want to dynamically pass the `form_class` in my view so that a single view can do all the work. Also, I don't want to use if condition because that would not serve the purpose.

**urls.py:**

```
url(r'^(?P<form>[\w-]+)/$',BillCycleCreateView.as_view(),name='BillCycle'),
```

**views:**

```
class BillCycleCreateView(CreateView):
    template_name = 'form-view.html'
    success_url = '.'
    def get_form_class(self):
        print(self.kwargs)
        x = self.kwargs['form'] 
        print(x)
        return x
```

The following code raises error that `str object is not callable`. Is there any way to fix it or any other way to achieve the desired result? How can I return a class?

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

You need an if statement to convert the string you get from the URL (variable `x` in your example) to an actual form class.

Comment: but then I have to write various if statements, and the purpose won't be served.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
def get_form_class(self):
    if self.kwargs['form'] == 'form_1':
        return MyForm_1
    elif self.kwargs['form'] == 'form_2':
        return MyForm_2
    else:
        raise Exception('We have an unknown parameter in the url')
```

A better exception message is advised.